# Is there a widely available C++ version of Java's NavigableMap interface?

Tags: java, c++, sorting, stl, dictionary

In Java, you can have a [NavigableMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html), which lets you do useful things such as "find the greatest key less than or equal to the given value" (floorKey method).  So if `myMap` contains {1->"One", 2->"Two", 3->"Three", 7->"Seven"}, you can call `myMap.floorKey(6)` and it will return the key of `3`.

In C++, STL provides a [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) class, which by default sorts entries according to ascending key value order.  This is great, but how can I do something similar to floorKey in C++?  All the references I've found so far suggest you have to do it manually (i.e. define an iterator, converge on the key - preferably using binary search, then find the next lower key).  Is there a widely-available library function available to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way to get this in C++ would be to call `map::upper_bound` and decrement the returned iterator:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
        std::map<int, std::string> myMap =
               {{ 1, "One"},
                {2, "Two"},
                {3, "Three"},
                {7, "Seven"}};

        auto i = myMap.upper_bound(6);
        std::cout << (--i)->first << '\n';
}
```

but beware of corner cases (if `upper_bound` returned `begin()`, or the map is empty, etc)

test run: https://ideone.com/TP3DL

Comment: `lower_bound` will not work the same way as `floorKey` -> "find the greatest key **less than or equal** to the given value". A call to `(--lower_bound(7))->first` would still yield `3`.

Comment: @Xeo: yes, I noticed that just before your answer.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I still got your unedited answer loaded when I wrote that comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use a priority queue.  Is there a reason you must use a map?